# Is there a way to convert the clipboard content into list in the run in Python?

Tags: python, list, clipboard

I would like to append two lists ("a"&"b") in Python, I have the list "b" coded in python, but the list "a" come from clipboard (always is different).

eg.

```
a = ["car", "plane", "truck", "motorcycle", "jet", "train"] # this list come from clipboard, always change
Clipboard = ["car", "plane", "truck", "motorcycle", "jet", "train"]
b = ["plane", "jet"] # this list is always the same
```

Is there a way to convert the clipboard content into list "a" in the run (interactively)???

Thanks Advanced.

Comment: Are you asking how to read the clipboard? There's no portable way, but there are ways for (at least) Mac OS X, Windows, X11, linuxconsole, and any text console with gpm. And, if you're building a GUI app, many GUI frameworks like Qt wrap up all the different platform-specific things in a consistent API, so each one of them adds yet another possible answer to your question. So… which one do you want?

Comment: But why are you trying to read the clipboard instead of just reading user input, so the user can paste whatever they want (or type something out manually instead, or pipe in output from a file, etc.)?

Comment: It can only be the clipboard, user are not involved at all in this task, my clipboard = ["car", "plane", "truck", "motorcycle", "jet", "train"] I just would like to convert it into a List. Thanks Advanced.

Comment: I am going to answer my own question, I just needed to use AsList = eval(a) It was so easy!

Comment: That's a really bad answer. What happens if someone—intentionally or accidentally—puts, say, `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')` on the clipboard (maybe because they selected this comment in the browser…) and then runs your program? If you really need to parse a Python-source-style list, use `ast.literal_eval`, not `eval`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you trying to simply read the clipboard and split the contents?
On linux:

```
import pyperclip
print pyperclip.paste().split(" ")
```

Windows:

```
from Tkinter import Tk
root = Tk()
print Tk.clipboard_get(root).split(" ")
```

OS X:

```
from AppKit import *
pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
pbstring = pb.stringForType_(NSStringPboardType)
print pbstring.split(" ")
```

**[EDIT]**

It looks as though `pyperclip` should work under windows and OS X as well, so that seems to be a portable solution. Ref: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyperclip/

Comment: The `Tk` solution is also cross-platform—but it requires running as a GUI app, which means it won't work over, say, an ssh connection on any platform, and on Windows it may require you to do the stupid pythonw thing, and it may pop up a window on any platform. Oh, and on OS X, I'm pretty sure PyObjC is going to give you back a `unicode`, so you definitely don't want to call `repr` on it (unless you want extra quotes and a `u` prefix), and you should `split(u" ")`.

Comment: That just makes it worse; you're calling `repr`, which is already going to encode it to UTF-8 and wrap it in quotes and prefix a `u`. And `u"%s".encode("utf-8")` is just the same thing as `"%s"`. All of that is unnecesasry; just `print pbstring`.

Comment: I actually would like to apply on Sikuli, so I would prefer avoid importing any module, thanks

Comment: It looks like, while this is a great answer to the question the OP asked, it's not relevant to the question he _wanted_ to ask. He's not actually trying to get the contents of the clipboard, he's just trying to parse something that happens to have come from the clipboard.

Comment: @litu16: For `sikuli`, you're running inside the JVM. So, if you can get the system clipboard, you'd do it by calling Java stdlib methods. (I don't know if that's possible.) But since that isn't your question anyway (if you thought `eval` was the answer, you're not looking to read the clipboard), it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it's become clear that you're not actually asking how to read the contents of the clipboard; you're just asking how to parse some data that happen to have come from the clipboard (presumably by you/the user manually pasting it).

So the real question is: how do you parse something that looks kind of like a list literal from Python source?

If it actually *is* a list literal from Python source, you use the [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast-helpers) function from the `ast` module:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "['a',2, (4,'b')]"
>>> lst = ast.literal_eval(s)
>>> print(lst)
['a', 2, (4, 'b')]
```

However, if you don't actually know where the data come from, there's a good chance it's actually JSON (which you should parse with `json.loads`), YAML, or some other format that's superficially similar to Python literals but not identical. If you try to parse JSON with `literal_eval`, it'll work on your initial tests, and then fail in real life because of a `false` instead of `False` or similar. That's why it's important to actually know what kind of data you have. If it came from Python source code, or from some Python script calling `print` with a list, that's what `literal_eval` is for.

Answer (score 0):

Try Pandas read_clipboard:

```
import pandas
pandas.read_clipboard(header=None)
```

This should return you a DataFrame. See info on parameters in documentation for pandas.read_table().